# Saving a web page from IE using Powershell

Tags: .net, internet-explorer, powershell, automation

I use the automation interface of Internet Explorer from Powershell to open a web page in a supported format. I want to save this page back to disk in one of the formats supported by IE. Opening the page is easy:

```
$ie = New-Object -ComObject "InternetExplorer.Application"
$ie.Navigate("C:\MyFile.mht")
```

How do I save it back in another format?

I need a solution that does not prompt the user since the idea is to automate this in a script running through multiple files.

Answer (score 3):

[You want to call ExecWB with the appropriate args](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752117(VS.85).aspx):

```
$ie.ExecWB(4,0,$null,[ref]$null)
```

Explanation of the 4 params:

```
4 = OLECMDID_SAVEAS
0 = OLECMDEXECOPT_DODEFAULT (This can also be 2 = OLECMDEXECOPT_DONTPROMPTUSER to not prompt and just save)
$null = NULL (I think this can be a path to save to: separate folders with 2 slashes (\\))
[ref]$null = ref NULL :)
```

Comment: Thanks! I can specify filename and extension (filetype) directly in parameter 3. But I still get the dialog box prompt, even when using "2" (DONTPROMPTUSER). That means I can't automate this in a script using multiple files. Do you know a solution to this?