# Converting mht to html

Tags: java, html, mhtml

I am receiving mht file. i need to txtract the text from this file and continue with some buisness logic.

Is there a way to extract text from mht file?

Is there a way to convert the MHT to html?

Comment: Isn't this question of these: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16203002/how-can-you-programmatically-or-with-a-tool-convert-mht-mhtml-files-to-regula

Answer (score 0):

Since MHTML is basically a MIME document containing the original HTML file and all of its resources, you can use a MIME library to extract the different parts. Be aware that all references in the html file inside the mht file may reference the original location of embedded files and you need to reconstruct those references from the Content-Location header of the MIME parts.