# get webpage html and css code from Matlab

Tags: html, css, matlab

I would like to get full webpage code using Matlab, but function urlread returns only html code. Is there any solution to get full page code as if I downloaded it using "Save as" in browser?

Thank you.

Comment: what do you want to get? the assets?

Comment: What plattform (MS Windows|Linux)?

Comment: I would like to get html, css and javascript code of page, but urlread gives only html. If i choose "Save as" option in browser I can get this, but didn't know how to do this from Matlab. Maybe there are some other options too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On MS Windows, you can use

```
ie = actxserver('internetexplorer.application')
ie.Navigate('http://sample.com/mydocument.html')
ie.ExecWB(4,2,'foo.html')
```

See [saving-a-web-page-from-ie-using-powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/872750/saving-a-web-page-from-ie-using-powershell) for an explanation of ExecWB().
You may not get rid of the prompt, so no automation.